# Spring Data JPA: Projection gets broken after adding pagination

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a query that uses projections, it works well as long as the return type is `List`, but it stops working after adding pagination.

Here is the the working code:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT \n" +
        "  new com.mycompany.dto.MyDto(me.property1, me.property2, ...) \n" +
        "FROM MyEntiry me...")
List<MyDto> findEntities();
```

I need to extend it adding pagination, so I change it to:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT \n" +
        "  new com.mycompany.dto.MyDto(me.property1, me.property2, ...) \n" +
        "FROM MyEntiry me...")
Page<MyDto> findEntities(Pageable pageable);
```

Once I do that the context starts failing because while parsing it inserts `select count(me)` between `SELECT` and `FROM` statements so that **the query become invalid**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  new com.mycompany.dto.MyDto(me.property1, me.property2, ...)  
select count(me) FROM com.mycompany.MyEntiry me ...
```

The context fails with the following exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected token: select near line 3, column 1 [SELECT DISTINCT    new
>   com.mycompany.dto.MyDto(me.property1, me.property2, ...) **select
>   count(me)** FROM com.mycompany.MyEntiry me ...]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:291)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:186)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
>       ... 88 more

**Question:** How to make it work? Is it Spring Data bug?

**Note:**

- The query I added is oversimplified, my real query in fact gathers  different values from different tables and I can't implement it without projections
- I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'native' Spring Data JPA [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

This should work well:

```
public interface MyProjection {
    String getProperty1();
    //...
}

Page<MyProjection> getDistinctAllBy(Pageable pageable);
```

But, if your query joins many tables you cannot use the pagination without some pain (for example: [1](https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/), [2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/c1906431c62179eb0a41c86d687cd7149ea5280e/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java#L427))

**UPDATED**

Try to add parameter [countQuery](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#countQuery--) to `@Query` annotation:

```
@Query(value = "select ...", countQuery = "select count(me) from MyEntiry me")
Page<MyDto> findEntities(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: That was my initial idea. I couldn't map query results. Somehow it is unable to match the query results with the methods from the interface (I named the results in correspondence to the projections methods `String geName()` -> `select me.name AS name, ...`). The only way it worked is by explicitly calling constructor from the DTO.