# Spring Data The return type is an abstract class or interface error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a stupid question. I don't understand why my Spring Data Repository method using Projections produces this compilation error.

I have a repository class

```
@Repository
public interface MyClassRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Long> {
  Page<MyProjection> getResultsByParam(@Param("param") Long personId,
                                                 Pageable pageable, Sort sort);
}
```

and the Projection (I have a large hibernate connected object, from which I want only a few fields)

```
public interface MyProjection {
  Type getType();

  Status getStatus();

  SubItem getDocument();

  interface SubItem {
    String getName();
  }
}
```

When I try to call the method from a service I get

```
error: The return type is an abstract class or interface. Provide a non abstract / non interface result type or a factory method.
```

I call the Service like this, where the compilation error is.

```
myClass.getResultsByParam(param, page, sort)
```

I am quite sure that, I have something really simple wrong here...

Comment: I've done this before without a problem but I usually have to create projections for all my subtypes, I see you nested the SubItem, what happened to the others? Additionally, I always just have their own projection interface files, not nested. Not sure if that's a factor here.

Comment: When reading the documentation I do not see any reference that I should do subtypes in separate files (looking at spring data documentation), also sadly this cannot be the cause of the problem. It should be architectural, at least I think or the error would be different.

Answer (score -1):

Spring data autogenerates code to fulfil that repository interface. This code will contain code creating the result object. To be able to create the result object, the object has be be instantiable; abstract classes and interfaces are not.

You have to change your interface method to something like

```
Page<MyProjectionImpl> getResultsByParam(@Param("param") Long personId,
                                             Pageable pageable, Sort sort);
```

where `MyProjectionImpl` is an `@Entity` that has a default constructor and getters/setters for the properties, so Spring Data can fill them.

Comment: I have not seen any examples where the Projection interface is actually implemented, I have seen a DTO approach. Still, shouldn't SpringData just generate the implication? Can't it be my configuration somehow.

Comment: For example the first response here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391119/spring-data-jpa-projection-gets-broken-after-adding-pagination